# Dynamically Add Buttons, Input Fields to Form from MySQL Result

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, compact-framework

If I have this table in a mysql database for example

```
table: people
id        fname        lname        age        profession
1         Gordon       Batonvere    32         Teacher
2         Baron        Greenstick   45         Engineer
. . .
```

And using this bit of mysql on the form, I can get the results:

```
private void viewFormOne_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string conn = "server=localhost;database=dbname;user=username;password=password;";


            MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM `people`";
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, myconn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, there are no records to show.", "No Records");
            }
            else
            {
               //What to do here is what I don't know how to go about
            }
       }
```

How do I display that data on the form like this:

```
NAME: Gordon Batonvere
AGE: 32

------------------------
| DISPLAY FULL PROFILE |    //This is a button
------------------------

.. ..  And so on
```

How do I get the labels and buttons to display dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Add a button manually to your form using the form designer, then examine the code that is generated in your form's designer.cs file. The process is very simple - it requires creating a button object, setting its location within the form, and assigning it to an event handler to execute code when it is clicked. Here is a very simple example:

```
    this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
    this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(86, 101);
    this.button1.Name = "button1";
    this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
    this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
    this.button1.Text = "button1";
    this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
    this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

The process for labels and other form controls is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a custom control, so you do not have to create and position two label and text boxes plus the button sepratelyy for each entry. Create a panel and place the labels, textboxes and the button on it. Have two public properties to set the Name and Age text (or use a label). You may even use a custom class inititiator to set the Name and Age directly when you add a new entry (custom control).